# Julian Day time to military time - R

Tags: r, time, datetime-format, julian-date

I want to convert the following JD time format to its intuitively interpretable military format ("%H:%M:%S"):

[Julian Day time format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U85tP.png)

Is there a function in R to do this? Any suggestions on how to convert to the desired military time format ("%H:%M:%S")?

Comment: Could you please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: convert the time to seconds by multiplying by 24hr*3600 seconds and then convert to a datetime object `as.POSIXct(t*24*3600, origin="2022-07-08")`, now format to desired output.

Comment: @Quinten `c(0.388025231484789, 0.388718518515816, 0.389415509256651, 0.390111689812329, 
0.390806828705536, 0.392295023149927)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this (thanks to @Dave2e):

```r
your_julian <- c(0.388025231484789, 0.388718518515816, 0.389415509256651, 0.390111689812329, 0.390806828705536, 0.392295023149927)
your_date <- as.POSIXct(your_julian*24*3600, origin="2022-07-08")
strftime(your_date, format="%H:%M:%S") 
#> [1] "11:18:45" "11:19:45" "11:20:45" "11:21:45" "11:22:45" "11:24:54"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That's definitely very helpful! Thanks! @Quinten

Comment: Thanks again, implementation works flawless!