# Convert hours that are given as a proportion into hours and minutes

Tags: r, date, timestamp

I have a date set where the hour of purchase is given as a proportion of 24 hours, so 0.5 is noon for example.

Now, I want to convert these proportions into a normal time with hours:minutes. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert decimal hours to HH:MM:SS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721145/convert-decimal-hours-to-hhmmss)

Comment: Also see this recent question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72910524/julian-day-time-to-military-time-r#comment128778813_72910524

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem?

```
library(lubridate)
as.period(ddays(fraction))
```